# How to use wkhtmltopdf with Docker

Tags: docker, wkhtmltopdf

When I use wkhtmltopdf (version 0.12.2.4, installed via apt-get) within a Docker container it fails with

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

(When I set the environment variable `DISPLAY=unix0`, I get `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display unix0` which makes sense as no Xserver seems to be installed)

There seems to be a headless version ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551105/562769)) and I thought that would mean that I don't need an Xserver.

(`xvfb` seems to be another option, but I'm not sure how to run it / what to install)

**How can I run wkhtmltopdf in a Docker container, if I can't change the base image to `openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing version `0.12.4` (I had `0.12.2.2` before) solved the problem. See [How can I install the latest wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/959152/10425) for the steps.